# Is there a cap for cooldown reduction (CDR) in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

At what point does cooldown reduction cap out? Is it possible to hit the cap with only masteries and runes?

Comment: The CDR cap is still 40%, but in season 6 there is a mastery that raises it to **45%**. This may be changed in season 7.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Cooldown reduction (CDR) has a hard cap at 40%.**

You can get **10%** CDR from masteries alone (9/0/21), and **7.50%** from flat cooldown glyphs or **10%** from scaling CDR glyphs, a little more if you invest in CDR seals or marks (though they will provide a lesser amount than the glyphs.

If you're playing Summoner's Rift, the Crest of the Ancient Golem provides a buff giving scaling mana regen and a flat cooldown reduction bonus of **10%**.

You can hit the cap with a 9/0/21 mastery page in conjunction with scaling CDR glyphs, a blue buff, and an Elixir of Brilliance (blue pot).

However, *you cannot hit the cap using only masteries and runes*. You can get up to **32.5%**: **10%** from a 9/0/21 mastery page, **1.8%** from flat CDR marks, **3.2%** from flat CDR seals, **10%** from scaling CDR glyphs, and **7.5%** from scaling CDR quintessences.

Comment: 11% CDR from masteries alone? I can only achieve 9% on my side. [intelligence: +6% / sorcery: +3%]. Did I missed something? In the same way Quintessences+Glyph+mark+Seal sum up to 19.2% on my calculator (So this sum up to 28.2% /w neutral buff). Maybe I'm not uptodate?

Comment: He is including Blue buff in the calculations

Comment: @M'vy - math fixed.