# What is the maximum amount of cooldown reduction I can get?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a cap for cooldown reduction (CDR) in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/is-there-a-cap-for-cooldown-reduction-cdr-in-league-of-legends)

When should I stop getting cooldown reduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40 percent CDR is max.  Remember that masteries and runes count towards this, and also the blue buff.  The blue buff gives 20 percent CDR last time I checked.  Often, if you are a caster you'll be grabbing the blue anyway.  It depends on your team composition and if others on your team need that blue.

Comment: Given that it is now 2017. And numerous patches have been released since then. Does this standard still hold? I can't seem to find documentation anywhere

Answer (score 2):

The Maximum cooldown reduction you can have is 40%.

Answer (score 1):

The max reduction is 40% and you can't get more than that, so don't go over 40 if you want to max.

Answer (score 1):

It caps at 40% cooldown reduction, if my memory serves me, so you should stop at that point.